# Symony2 Access form in entity prePersist?

Tags: php, symfony, entity

Title says it all. I want to be able to access the form from within my prePersist function in my entity. Something like this:

```
/** @ORM\PrePersist */
public function prePersist()
{
    //Symfony 1.4 way
    $params     = sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParameterHolder()->getAll();
    $this->gps84Long=$params['coordinate']['gps_84_lat_degrees'];

}
```

The reason I need this is because the form values are not mapped to the database fields. I need to combine 2-3 form fields into one value to be placed into a single field in my entity.

EDIT- added .yml addition for provided answer:

```
services:

   my.doctrine.subscriber:  
     class:  myCompany\myBundle\Models\MyDoctrineSubscriber
     arguments:  [@form.factory,"@request_stack"]
     tags:
       - { name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber', connection: 'default' }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a data transformer which can map multiple fields into one?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html. The problem with using onPersist is that you will probably want to be able to update the values as well and onUpdate does not always work as desired.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Could you elaborate on the issues with onUpdate?

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a [Doctrine subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) and inject whatever service you want (xml example):

service.xml

```
<service id="my.doctrine.subscriber" class="%my.doctrine.subscriber.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="form.factory" />
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack" />
    <tag name="doctrine.event_subscriber" connection="default" />
</service>
```

MyDoctirneSubscriber

```
class MyDoctirneSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $formFactory;

    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'prePersist',
            ...
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entityManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof MyEntity) {
            $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

            $form = $this->formFactory->create(TYPE, DATA_OR_NULL, OPTIONS);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            ....
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: So would all entities go through this function when persisted? And do you happen to know the .yml representation of the service? Thats what I've been using. I know how to represent everything but the arguments.

Comment: @KiraisJustice Yes, all entities go through this method, that's why we put a condition (`if ($entity instanceof MyEntity)` - Doctrine recommendation). Sorry, I've never used yml service definition..